# using php functions in twig

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

Right now I have the game account number which is showing all the numbers, but what I want is to only show the last 4 numbers.I am pretty new to Symfony, so my question is how can I have this code in twig ? Or Do I have to do it the controller ? Thanks in advance...

So what I want is this, which is the the code I want in twig. My confusion is dispalying this code in the twig:

```
$gameId = '123456789';
$gameId = str_repeat('*', strlen($gameId) - 4) . substr($gameId, -4);

var_dump($gameId); //outputs  *****6789
```

this is what I already have, which is showing all the numbers that is being displayed from the form...

```
  <input value="{{ gameAccount.getAccountNumber() }}" 
    class="form-control" 
    dataid="{{ gameAccount.getId() }}" id="inputAccountNumber{{ gameAccount.getId() }}" 
    value="{# { gameAccount.getAccountNumber() } #}" 
    placeholder="Account Number" 
    type="text">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a Twig Extension to do the job.

```
namespace AppBundle\Twig;

class AppExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFilter('censorship', array($this, 'censorship')),
        );
    }

    public function censorship($id)
    {
        return str_repeat('*', strlen($id) - 4) . substr($id, -4);
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'app_censorship';
    }
}
```

Then you register the extension as a service

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.twig_extension:
        class: AppBundle\Twig\AppExtension
        public: false
        tags:
            - { name: twig.extension }
```

and call it in you template like this

```
{{ gameAccount.getAccountNumber()|censorship }}
```

You can read more about it in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html).

Comment: I am using twig and do not have the services.yml. I installed twig via composer.

Where would I tell twig to make the function available to my twig templates?

Comment: When you're using twig standalone, https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/advanced.html#filters